# Action immediately after selecting Item

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

I have this code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "blahblah")
        {
            processing ps = new processing();
            pictureBox1.Image = ps.blahblah(bmp);
        }
        else
        {...
        }
    }
```

So the action of the ComboBox is done by clicking on the button1.
It is possible to take action immediately after selecting Item? without button clicking?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subscribe to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += OnSelectedIndexChanged;

private void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // Handle combo box changing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this event,

```
ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
```

and do

```
AutoPostBack = "true"
```

in your mark up if you want to check the selected item immediately after selecting item.